# 4 authors, but half of the final author's name is moved to next lne. How can I stop it?

Tags: formatting, elsarticle

We have 4 authors. However when I use elsarticle 2 things are happening:
1. it does not give me an option to put word "and" before the 4th author's name
2. Due to the length of names, 4th author's name is divided in half and first name is shown on the first line and the last name is in a new line. How do I get around this?

Comment: I wouldn't care.  If you're using `elsarticle`, you are probably going to publish in one of Elsevier's journals, and they have a very good TeX crew from River Valley Technologies, who kind of rewrite your LaTeX file anyway (mostly automatically).  In a pinch, just email the maintainers of the `elsarticle` class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a "tie" symbol, `~`, between the first and last name of the fourth author?

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to your question. It could help to visualize the problem.

Comment: Ad 2: have you tried `\mbox{First Last}`?

Comment: As it stands, this really doesn't seem clear: we need a minimal working example to hope to help.